duplicate .dockerfile file in a project structure. How to run the docker build command for second .dockerfile file which in present in a sub-folder?
I have a my main .dockerfile in my projects parent directory which is responsible to create the docker-image for my application. My scenario is I want to run my heartbeat jobs in ECS container. To do this I have to create the specific .dockerfile and the infrastructure as a  code (Terraform) scripts. I have created the .dockerfile in a subfolder and I am trying to run the docker build command but I am getting below error.
Step 8/11 : COPY /home/shrirang2004/project-name/target/project-name-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /opt/project-name/jarFile/
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat home/shrirang2004/project-name/target/project-name-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar: file does not exist


The error posted indicates that the jar file is not present or not accessible from /home/shrirang....Are you sure the jar file is present in the right path

Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  What exactly is in the (subdirectory) Dockerfile, and what command or configuration are you using to build the image?  The left-hand side of COPY is always relative to a specific directory (the build context) passed as an argument to the builder, so the absolute path in the error message suggests you're trying to incorrectly use a full host-system path.
